# Submit multiple form values with AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularfire

I try to understand how AngularFire works. I'm trying to save a first name and a last name to my firebase database. I successfully created a "first name" input and saved it in Firebase. I now try to add a last name input but I can't figure how to make it works. Here is what I get up to now:

**HTML**

```
<section ng-controller="premiercontrolleur">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="client in clients">
    <input ng-model="client.prenom" ng-change="clients.$save(client)" />
    <input ng-model="client.nom" ng-change="clients.$save(client)" />
    <button ng-click="clients.$remove(client)">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<form ng-submit="addClient(newClientText)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Prénom" ng-model="newClientText.prenom" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nom de famille" ng-model="newClientText.nom" />
  <button type="submit">Ajouter le client</button>
</form>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("crmfirebase", ["firebase"]);

app.controller("premiercontrolleur", function($scope, $firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://mydirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/clients");
  var sync = $firebase(ref);

  $scope.clients = sync.$asArray();

  $scope.addClient = function(prenom) {
    $scope.clients.$add({prenom: prenom, nom: nom});
  }
});
```

I got this error on submit:

```
Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('submit') does not support selection.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching good the values, remember that prenon is a object that has the properties prenon and nom, so try:

```
  $scope.addClient = function(prenom) {
    $scope.clients.$add({prenom: prenom.prenom, nom: prenom.nom});
  }
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Now I understand and I also changed function(prenom) to function(client) with client.prenom and client.nom.

Comment: Yes you could uses whatever you want, but remember you are sending a object, only match the properties. :)